# Google maps get business/establishment name from places on drag?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have hit a wall with Google Maps api so looking for an answer. I am adding a location to an event I am creating, what I want to do is if a user can't find a location using a text search then they can drag the marker to the desired location whereby i set the details.

Here is a rough example of my code

```
function getLocationDetails(pos) {
   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
   geocoder.geocode({'location': pos}, function(results, status) {
     if (status === 'OK') {
       if (results[0]) {
         console.log(results);
         getPlaceName(results[0].place_id);                 
       } else {
         window.alert('No results found');
       }
     } else {
       window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
   });
}

function getPlaceName(pid){
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(data.map);

  service.getDetails({
    placeId: pid
  }, function(place, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    console.log(place.name);
  }
});
```

}

So basically what happens is that after the drag the marker and pass the pos it returns an array of results so i have no idea which one I should use, also it never seems to return a place name like i would expect say for example I want "The O2 in London" if i drag the marker onto the O2 then none of the results say "O2" in place.name! Any ideas what I am doing wrong anybody?

Many Thanks

Comment: Yes, that is pretty strange.  The O2 location returns: [0]: London. Only result [2] returns O2.  For the Eifel Tower it's result [3]; the Atomium result [2] ... The places clearly don't get sorted by (shortest) distance.  What might work: after you get a list of places, you should sort them by distance from the dragged marker, then choose the closest one

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Oddly for me O2 doesn't return at all or it is returned as the millenium dome which is very old!! It's only on drag thou if you use Autocomplete markers it returns O2, madness!! :)

Comment: If you are looking for business/establishment I believe the places library is a more appropriate choice. Have a look at nearby search of places library: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests. The reverse geocoding will return many different things apart of places.